# Mysql query, Get distance using current latitude longitude of user, group by branch and then finally get the nearest branch of the store

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to find the nearest branch of the store from user current location

My **restaurant Table** as like below image
[image]

[image]

Note : - one store can have multiple branches , so I use group by "brandcode"
MySQL version is : 8.0.21
I don't know how will I get nearest branch in group

```
SELECT a.*
     , POW(69.1 * (a.address_lat - 26.855298971417806), 2) + POW(69.1 * (75.81484306777995 - a.address_long) * COS(a.address_lat / 57.3), 2) AS distance 
  FROM restaurant as a 
 where city_id in (34) 
 group 
    by a.brandcode
 order 
    by distance ASC 
 limit 0 , 20
```

please help me

Thanks

Comment: Importantly, what is the MySQL version you're running?

Comment: *I want to find the nearest branch of the store* - **one** branch (not "branches") and `limit 0 , 20`? it's strange. *one store can have multiple branches , so I use group by "brandcode"* One branch may posess in a lot of different places?

Comment: Note that without a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table

Comment: Its just for example I have  PRIMARY KEY in my table and lot more other fields Like store lat, log  etc.

Comment: What is `brandcode`?  It is not in the sample data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one row per *branchcode*, then use window functions:

```
with r as (
      select r.*,
             POW(69.1 * (a.address_lat - 26.855298971417806), 2) + POW(69.1 * (75.81484306777995 - a.address_long) * COS(a.address_lat / 57.3), 2) AS distance 
      from restaurant r
      where r.city_id in (34) 
     )
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by branchcode order by distance) as seqnum
      from r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1
order by distance ASC 
limit 0, 20;
```